# Discord.py - How to get A's ID from B's message when B is sending a message that is replying to A's original message?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make a discord bot to automate playing my friend's bot's game. When my friend's bot sends a message replying to your message after you use a specific command. I want to be able to check if the message the bot sends is replying to my message specifically. This is what I've got so far:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.id == botId:
        content = str(message.content)
        reference = message.reference
        if reference.message_id.author.id == myId:
            word = content.split('`')[1].split('`')[0]
            await bot.send_message(message.channel, word)
```

I know `reference.message_id.author.id` will not work since *author.id* is incompatible with *reference.message_id*, but I cannot find something that will work with it.

The Error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\User\Projects\Programming\Python\Discord Bot\Waterhole Dryer\bot.py", line 30, in on_message
    if reference.message_id.author.id == myId:
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'author'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alrighty, so... I found a bit of a workaround to this...

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.id == botId:
        guild = bot.get_guild(guildId)
        channel = guild.get_channel(message.reference.channel_id)
        msg = await channel.fetch_message(message.reference.message_id)
        if msg.author.id == myId:
            word = content.split('`')[1].split('`')[0]
            await channel.send(word)
```

Basically, I made a **new** message object. I hope this helps anyone else with my problem.